# 5 small linear algebra questions

Tags: linear-algebra

What are all of the real numbers that can occur as values of the

(a) determinant
(b) trace
(c) pivots
(d) eigenvalues of $n \times n $ permutation matrices?

Justify your answers.

(a) Any real number, let's say $t$ can be the value of the determinant. Since the determinant of a matrix can be 0, negative and positive.

(b) The trace of a matrix is the sum of all it's diagonal entries hence the sum of the diagonal entries can be any real number also.

(c) The pivots of a RREF matrix must be 1 for the matrix to be in RREF. (I'm not really sure what they are asking here?)

(d) I couldn't really understand this question.

To be honest I didn't like the question it seems very vague and I'm not entirely sure what's being asked of me here. Is it just a very general question?

Comment: Do you know what are permutation matrices? Then the answers may seem a lot clearer. Otherwise, there is nothing in the question.

Comment: I think the questions are all about permutation matrices - do you know what a permutation matrix is?

Comment: Ah ok, no I don't so I'm just going to study what it is now.

Comment: In a $nxn$ permutation matrix (so called because it permutes the vectors in the associated basis) there are precisely $n$ entries which are $1$ - arranged so that there is one in each row and column - and the rest of the entries are zero.

Comment: Like the identity matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a permutation matrix

(a)The determinant of a permutation matrix is +1 or -1. Because a permutation matrix is orthogonal.

(b)The trace of an $n \times n$ permuation matrix is  $0\le Tr(A) \le n $ for $n \in \mathbb N$

(c) The number of pivots

(d) the eigenvalues of the permutation matrix $A$ is 1 (with a multiplicity of n)